# Processing: Is it possible, to scale the whole program?

Tags: processing, scaling

I'm kinda new to programming, and tried myself at some sort of comedic game. The game itself works just fine and as intended. The problem is, that its size is too big.

I sent the game to a friend, but the game size was much bigger than at my display. I programmed the game with a new notebook and used the overall size 1600 x 1200, because it looked good on it. But I forgot, that this is not the normal height but bigger than 1080.
Plus, I didn't know about displayHeight or Weight until it already happened.

And now I m in a kinda bad situation, at which I only can hope, that there is a scale command, to scale the whole program, with all in it.

Changing every number of every object, by myself, would mean changing every location of over plenty hundred different pictures and lines. This can be done, but it would be interesting, if there is another way to cheese around it.

Extra Info:

The used language is Processing.
The game is some sort of pile of different images and click checking, like the Maze game, where you need to navigate the mouse through a maze without hitting the walls.

Comment: What language? Is this is a web app?  Is it an executable?  There are so many factors here ...  but is it possible to scale things? sure .. but we need to know what code you are using and all that.

Of note ... you might of learned a valuable lesson though, this is a case where you might want to consider using variables for the values of the sizes so you can tweak the numbers and not the whole code.

Comment: @easleyfixed Please read the tag info. *"What language?"* - The language is [Processing](https://processing.org/)

Comment: OH my bad its a generic term that someone made into a lanuage? okay cool .. threw me off since use of the generic term scaling was tagged as well ..

Comment: @easleyfixed Yes, I'm sure, I won't ever use no variables anymore for these kinds of things. In my next program, I will try to avoid all the mistakes I made there.

Comment: On the setup function you can set the size of the window using the size(w,h) function. If you want it to adapt to the screen then you can use https://processing.org/reference/displayWidth.html and its related dispayHight, or if you want the program to always use the whole screen then instead of size() you can just call fullScreen(). Read more about it here: https://processing.org/reference/size_.html

Answer (score 1):

I have made a quick test on my game, and it's basically work:

```
void draw() {
  scale(0.67);
  // your game...
}
```